# Swift: fatal error: Index out of range

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, indexing

I'm getting an "Index out of range" when populating a UITableView.
I don't know why it gives me error. I have a condition statement on my cell creation function which checks for the count of each array and then adds a custom cell on index 0.

If anyone knows about this problem, please tell me the solution. I've been working on it for days and can't seem to figure this one out.

```
var homeArr: [services] = []
var autoArr: [services] = []

Alamofire.request(url_specialist_request_url, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON {
    response in

    if response.data != nil {
        let json = JSON(data: response.data!)
        let json_count = json.count

        // print(json)

        self.homeArr.append(services(service_name:"",service_icon:"",service_category:""))
        self.autoArr.append(services(service_name:"",service_icon:"",service_category:""))
        self.personalArr.append(services(service_name:"",service_icon:"",service_category:""))

        for i in 0 ..< json_count {
            let categoryId = json[i]["category_id"].string!
            if(categoryId == "1") {
                self.homeArr.append(services(service_name:json[i]["service_name"].string!,service_icon:"\(json[i]["service_icon"].string!)Icon",service_category:json[i]["category_id"].string!))
            } else if(categoryId == "2") {
                self.autoArr.append(services(service_name:json[i]["service_name"].string!,service_icon:"\(json[i]["service_icon"].string!)Icon",service_category:json[i]["category_id"].string!))
            } else {
                self.personalArr.append(services(service_name:json[i]["service_name"].string!,service_icon:"\(json[i]["service_icon"].string!)Icon",service_category:json[i]["category_id"].string!))
            }
        }

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "serviceCell",for:indexPath) as! servicesCell

    let home_dict = self.homeArr[indexPath.row]
    // ** Index out of range on the following line **
    let auto_dict = self.autoArr[indexPath.row]

    if(self.homeArr.count > 1) {
        if (indexPath.row == 0)
        {
            cell.serviceLabel!.text = "Home"
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        } else {
            cell.serviceLabel!.text = home_dict.service_name
            cell.serviceIcon!.image = UIImage(named:"\(home_dict.service_icon)")
        }
    }

    if(self.autoArr.count > 1) {
        if (indexPath.row == 0)
        {
            cell.serviceLabel!.text = "Personal"
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        } else {
            cell.serviceLabel!.text = auto_dict.service_name
            cell.serviceIcon!.image = UIImage(named:"\(auto_dict.service_icon)")
        }
    }

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return(homeArr.count + arrAuto.count)
}
```

This is what I want to achieve

  Home Arr cell

value1

value2

  Auto Arr cell

value1

value2

Comment: Start by pointing out the exact line of code causing the error.

Comment: @IGNITER you did return(homeArr.count + arrAuto.count) means if you have 10 values in each array, the number of rows goes 20. Now in cell method you are doing self.homeArr[indexPath.row] and self.autoArr[indexPath.row] . Your array holds 10 index but method is calling for 20 so index out of range.

Comment: @TusharSharma What do you think would be the work around? I have no idea.

Comment: @rmaddy it errors this line     let auto_dict = self.autoArr[indexPath.row]

Comment: How do you want to show your data in the table view? You have two arrays of data that you seem to want to display. Do you want a row for each value in the `homeArr` and a row for each value in `autoArr`? Do you want to show all of the rows for `autoArr` after the rows for the `homeArr`? Please explain your goal.

Comment: @rmaddy Basically, I want to display the content of homeArr and autoArr.

Comment: Please read my comment again. How do you want to display the content of those two arrays? Be specific and clear.

Comment: @rmaddy I've edited my post, and added what I want to achieve on my table. please refer above, thanks.

Comment: @IGNITER That doesn't clear up anything at all. That is now more confusing.

Comment: @rmaddy actually, all i want is a header section for each category types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two sections One for HomeArr and one for AutoArr. I believe for each section you wanna show a additional cell with some title. So below code should help you.

```
extension ViewController : UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 0 {
            return (homeArr.count > 0) ?  homeArr.count + 1 : 0
        }
        else {
            return (autoArr.count > 0) ?  autoArr.count + 1 : 0
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "serviceCell",for:indexPath) as! servicesCell
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            if (indexPath.row == 0)
            {
                cell.serviceLabel!.text = "Home"
                cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
            } else {
                let home_dict = self.homeArr[indexPath.row - 1]
                cell.serviceLabel!.text = home_dict.service_name
                cell.serviceIcon!.image = UIImage(named:"\(home_dict.service_icon)")
            }
        }
        else {
            if (indexPath.row == 0)
            {
                cell.serviceLabel!.text = "Personal"
                cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
            } else {
                let auto_dict = self.autoArr[indexPath.row - 1]
                cell.serviceLabel!.text = auto_dict.service_name
                cell.serviceIcon!.image = UIImage(named:"\(auto_dict.service_icon)")
            }
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

As pointed out by [rmaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1226963/rmaddy) in comments below

> Why the extra row in each section? Why not use a section header
>   instead?

As we are not aware of OP's exact requirement I am updating my code to show section title as well.

```
 extension ViewController : UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 0 {
            return homeArr.count
        }
        else {
            return autoArr.count
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "serviceCell",for:indexPath) as! servicesCell
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            let home_dict = self.homeArr[indexPath.row]
            cell.serviceLabel!.text = home_dict.service_name
            cell.serviceIcon!.image = UIImage(named:"\(home_dict.service_icon)")
        }
        else {
            let auto_dict = self.autoArr[indexPath.row]
            cell.serviceLabel!.text = auto_dict.service_name
            cell.serviceIcon!.image = UIImage(named:"\(auto_dict.service_icon)")
        }
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        if section == 0 {
            return "Home Arr cell"
        }
        else {
            return "Auto Arr cell"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the extra row in each section? Why not use a section header instead?

Comment: @rmaddy  : OP hasn't posted any image showing his requirement. In his code OP added a new cell so made assumption that he dont want a section header and needs a seamless cell flow. Not sure of requirement fully hence added.

Comment: @rmaddy : Attempt was to keep the code change minimal. As he add already added a if condition to check row == 0 so I thought Ill not return a section header.

Comment: Hopefully the OP will eventually be able to answer my questions about how they want the array data displayed but so far, no luck.

Comment: @rmaddy : Any way am updating my answer to reflect your suggestion of section header as well :)

Comment: @rmaddy A header section, but what I want to retain the header once im going to filter my table, and im not sure if the header will retain if the table will be filtered.

Comment: @SandeepBhandari , Yes all i need is a header

Comment: @SandeepBhandari anyway i've tried your code, it still throws me a index out of range

Comment: @igniter : Can you be little more specific and point out which line you are getting error? I dont have full code to compile so cant guess where the issue might be

Comment: it's still the same line, where the error is occuring, let auto_dict = autoArr[indexPath.row]

Comment: @igniter : My bad:) Gimme a minute

Comment: @igniter : I hope u are using second EDIT code I have updated my Edit. Please check

Comment: @igniter : Now I have updated both solutions use whichever works for u :D

Comment: @igniter : What happened ? Still have issues ??

Comment: Thank you. i've resolved the problem by modifying parts of your answer.

Comment: @igniter : Am glad you managed to solve your problem buddy :) Happy coding